# Android - Wrong activity sometimes starts

Tags: android, android-activity, restart

I have an Android App with a number of activities. The wrong activity is being started sometimes.

Normally, an Application subclass starts, then start activity (**StartAct**... android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN", android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
does some work and then launches **InitializeActivity**. This does some work and then fires off my main display activity (**MainAct**). The first two activities do some essential initialization including setting a static "**isInitialized**" flag just before the intent is launched for the **MainAct**.

Activities are launched with startActivity() using a specific intent (...activity.class specified), and call finish() after startActivity().

However, here is what sometimes happen, and I don't know why...

In short, the app is killed and when the icon is pressed to start it, it jumps straight to the third (**MainAct**) activity. This causes the app to detect an error (**isInitialized** flag is false) and stop:

- Launch the app normally with the Icon:
- ...Application subclass starts, also fires up some worker threads
- ...**StartActivity** runs, then fires **InitializeActivity** and finishes
- ...**InitializeActivity** runs, then sets **isInitialized** and starts **MainAct** and finishes
- ...**MainAct** starts, runs okay
- ...Home button is hit and Angry Birds is run
- ...**MainAct** logs **onPause**, then **onStop**.
- ...Worker threads owned by Application subclass continue to periodically do stuff and log.
- After 25 minutes, the entire application is suddenly killed. This observation is based on thhe end of logging activity,
- Time goes by
- Home button hit
- Launcher ICON is pressed for the app
- Application subclass **onCreate** is called and returns
- ****MainAct.onCreate*** is called! (no **StartAct**, no **InitializeActivity**)*

What am I missing?

Note: the initialize flag was added because of this issue. It is set in the only place in the code that starts the main activity, and checked only in onCreate in the main activity.

[per request]
Manifest file (slightly redacted). Note that the service in here is not currently used.

```
<manifest
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="xxx.yyy.zzz"
  android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0.1">
  <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_nondistr"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".app.MainApp"
    android:debuggable="true">
    <activity
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:name=".app.StartAct" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
      <intent-filter>
        <action
          android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category
          android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
      android:label="Html"
      android:name=".app.HtmlDisplayAct"/>
    <activity
      android:label="Init"
      android:configChanges="orientation"
      android:name=".app.InitializeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>
    <activity
      android:label="MyPrefs"
      android:name=".app.PrefsAct" />
    <activity
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
      android:name=".app.MainAct">
    </activity>
    <service
      android:name=".app.svcs.DataGetterService" />
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"/>
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission
    android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
  <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
    android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: can you show your manifest file... seams like problem over there..

Comment: This is a very old posting, but I'm glad you posted it and I'm glad I found it. I could otherwise not believe that I was really experiencing what Android was doing with my app. Unfortunately the only answer is rather problematic - I'd have to add kludgy code to about 20 Activity classes to catch all possible cases. Did you ever find a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the application is killed because of low memory should be transparent to the users. This is why when the application is killed, Android remembers what was the last activity running in this application, and creates directly this activity when the user returns to the application.

Perhaps you could do something in the `onCreate()` method of your `Application` (or of your `MainAct`) to ensure that everything is properly initialized.

By the way, unless you really need to, you shouldn’t have worker threads doing some work when the user is not using your application. Depending on what you do this could drain the battery quickly, or make the user think that it could drain the battery quickly (which is worse, because the user will uninstall your app!)

You could also make the application finish every activity when the user is quitting the application,

Comment: Part of the functionality is to do periodic work in the background, so I do need worker threads somewhere (could be in a service, but they aren't). While I could have onCreate() insure initialization, this would not be easy (during initialization, I have a different activity so I can display stuff about the initialization). I couldn't find in the docs that Android does this behavior or I wouldn't have asked. Are you certain of this? Note that it is not transparent to the user - the user has to hit the activity icon again to restart it. Just backing up the stack doesn't start the app. Tks.

Comment: If you put your worker threads in a service, your app will probably not be killed and you will not have the problem. I’m not completely sure that what I’ve said is correct, but the doc says that _If an activity is paused or stopped, the system can drop the activity from memory by either asking it to finish, or simply killing its process. When it is displayed again to the user, it must be completely restarted and restored to its previous state._ [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), not sure what it means.

Comment: Another idea, don’t know if it would work, would be to declare `MainAct` to be the main activity (whose icon is displayed in the launcher) and make the `onCreate()` of the application run `StartActivity` (you will perhaps have to wait in `MainAct` for the initialisation to be complete).

Comment: I have considered your last suggestion before, and I think it is probably the right solution. Android seems to consider the first Activity and the most recent activity to both be special in some way, so it makes sense to make them the same. For now, I just detect the condition and have MainAct start StartAct and then finish(), which solves the problem, in an inelegant fashion. I hope some others chime in, but am marking this as the anwer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm also having this problem but this is a very very ugly solution. I do not know why Android would just decide to start an activity knowing that there are static references between it and just like in your case, items populated at startup.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a case of "adding insult to injury" - first Android kills my awesome app, and then when the user restarts my app Android tries to be "helpful" by launching the wrong activity, causing my app to crash. Sigh.

Here is my very kludgy workaround to counteract Android's helpfulness. My app requires that StartActivity must be the first activity, so for all other activities I add one line to the onCreate() method. For example:

```
public class HelpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      if (StaticMethods.switchToStartActivityIfNecessary(this))  return;  // <- this is the magic line

      ...

   }

  ...

}
```

To make this work I've added a switch variable to my Application class:

```
public class OutBackClientApplication extends Application {

   ...

   // Switch to indicate if StartActivity has been started.
   // Values: -1 = StartActity has never been started or this is first invocation.
   //         0 = normal situation, StartActivity has been run at least once.
   private int _startActivityStatus = -1;

   public int getStartActivityStatus() { return _startActivityStatus; }

   public void setStartActivityStatus(int startActivityStatus) {
      _startActivityStatus = startActivityStatus;
   }

   ...

}
```

And I have a class called StaticMethods, which includes the following method:

```
public class StaticMethods {

   /**
    * Method to test for the problematic situation where Android has previously killed this app, and
    * then when the user restarts the app Android tries to be helpful by restarting the activity
    * that was in the foreground when it killed the app, instead of starting the activity specified
    * in the manifest as the launch activity. See here:
    * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673271/android-wrong-activity-sometimes-starts
    *
    * The following line should be added to the onCreate() method of every Activity, except for
    * StartActivity, of course:
    *
    *    if (StaticMethods.switchToStartActivityIfNecessary(this))  return;
    */
   public static boolean switchToStartActivityIfNecessary(Activity currentActivity) {

      OutBackClientApplication outBackClientApplication =
                                        (OutBackClientApplication) currentActivity.getApplication();

      if (outBackClientApplication.getStartActivityStatus() == -1) {
         currentActivity.startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity, StartActivity.class));
         currentActivity.finish();
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

}
```

Finally, when StartActivity starts it needs to reset the switch:

```
 public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      ((OutBackClientApplication) getApplication()).setStartActivityStatus(0);

      ...

   }

   ...

}
```

All that, just to counteract Android's "helpfulness" ...